# Building a matrix

Tags: r

I want to construct a matrix of dimension T x T. In the first row and in the last column I want all zeros. Further, from second row up to row T and from the first column up to column T-1, I want an identity matrix. In the case where T=4, it should look something like this:

```
        1. column    2. column   3. column  4. column
1. row:     0           0           0           0

2. row:     1           0           0           0

3. row:     0           1           0           0

4. row:     0           0           1           0
```

I hope it makes sense,

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `? diag`, `rbind`, and `?cbind`:

```
n <- 4
rbind(rep(0, n), cbind(diag(1, n-1), rep(0, n-1)))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    1    0
```

(Note that `T` is often used as a shortcut for `TRUE` so you should avoid it as a variable name or you are going to have some problems...)

Comment: can also do `rbind(0, diag(1, n-1, n))`